# Installing ClickOnce application from ftp server

Tags: vb.net, ftp, clickonce

I have published a clickonce application to an ftp server but when I try to install it I get this message and the following error dialogue. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Could it possibly be the server or my code?

Error Message:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1055.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///C:/Users/XXXX/Downloads/DatabaseBackupApplication%20(6).application
    Deployment Provider url     : 

<Website Page Same as other 2>

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\DatabaseBackupApplication (6).application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading http://XXXX.co.uk/SoftwareUpdate/DatabaseBackupApplication.application did not succeed.
    + The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [08/03/2016 16:21:28] : Activation of C:\Users\XXXX\Downloads\DatabaseBackupApplication (6).application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [08/03/2016 16:21:28] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://XXXX.co.uk/SoftwareUpdate/DatabaseBackupApplication.application did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadManifestAsRawFile(Uri& sourceUri, String targetPath, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirect(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.FollowDeploymentProviderUri(SubscriptionStore subStore, AssemblyManifest& deployment, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

[image: Screenshot of theerror]

Comment: In your error message it says `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`. The installer could not find the file `http://<your website>/SoftwareUpdate/DatabaseBackupApplication.application`. Make sure everything's uploaded and put in their correct folders, and that the installer is correctly set up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for any reply I found out the problem was that the FTP I had was using a linux based system instead of windows. I got this sorted out now and thanks again.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, but you should have written this as a comment, not an answer.